# Websphere routing to file location instead of Controller

Tags: java, spring, websphere, websphere-liberty

I have a POST method which looks something like this:

```
http://SERVER-IP/demoapp/v2/mobile/message
```

and delivers with it a JSON payload. However, instead of routing to the correct controller as expected is appears to be searching for a file and throws the given exception:

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.service:1,624'
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /v2/mobile/message
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.service(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:1624)
    at [internal classes]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1287)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /v2/mobile/message
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:528)
    ... 12 more
```

I'm pretty new to Websphere so any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Also, for what its worth, I have previously gotten this to work correctly on Tomcat which leads me to believe it must be a configuration issue with Websphere.

The application is located under servers/demoServer/dropins/war/demoapp

I extracted the contents of the war file in that location.

**UPDATE:**
HERE is the method shell and web.xml as requested:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/v2/mobile/message",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> mobileDeviceMessagev2(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        ...code here....
}

    <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
      <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>inauth.perapp.log4j.properties</param-name>
        <param-value>${log4j.properties.collector.path}</param-value>
    </context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value></param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>com.inauth.fingerprint.collector.CollectorInitializer</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>collector</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
      <param-value>
          org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
      </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>com.inauth.fingerprint.collector.DispatcherConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>collector</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/static/404.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/static/500.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: what does your web.xml and/or @WebServlet annotation look like?

Comment: @aguibert - We don't use WebServlet but rather RequestMapping. I have added the method shell and web.xml to my question. Thanks.

Comment: If you need Rest service, Liberty provides full support Java EE 7 and for JAX-RS out of the box, you dont need Spring for that, so I'd suggest rather using that support instead of Spring. But regarding your question check if your Spring servlet is initializing correctly, also there is well known migration issue with Spring apps - try to use expanded WAR deployment in Liberty instead of archived WAR.

Comment: @Gas - I did use an expanded WAR. Unfortunately we need to try and use Spring as this product will also need to support Tomcat and JBoss.

Comment: From the backtrace, Spring was called and is deferring static file handling to the container it's running in.   You probably want to ask a more spring-oriented question than a websphere one.